# How can I make a non-Swing button in Java?

Tags: java, swing, button, graphics2d

I am creating a game in which I have a menu with multiple views for selecting game type, options, etc. using game state transitions. Each of the menus will be actively rendered within a *JFrame* on *Canvas* objects. Since I am doing active rendering on every game state by drawing a *BufferedImage* to the *Canvas*, I can't use the *JButton* or any other *JComponent* or *Component* (awt) because the Graphics2D object can't draw them like:

```
Graphics2D g = bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
g.draw(new JButton("Click me"));
```

How can I implement a custom button that can receive mouse input and be drawn with a Graphics2D object?

Comment: You're implementing menus by drawing a picture of the whole menu? Doesn't sound sensible to me.

Comment: JButton provides a  paintAll(Graphics g) method. so you could set the buttons position and size and then call mybutton.paintAll(g). This method exists on all Components

Comment: What would sound sensible to you? I want to have the menu screen animated as well. Therefore, I need the whole menu to be rendered each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a mouse listener to the component you are drawling on and have it determine if a mouse click was in the area that you want to be a button or not.

Comment: _MouseListners_ can only be added to _Component_ objects. _Component_ objects cannot be drawn with a _Graphics2D_ object. That's my conundrum as stated in the question.

Comment: Canvas is a Component.  Add the mouse listener to the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a Canvas in an application that is already using Swing (JFrame is Swing)?

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(blah....)
Graphics2D gfx = image.createGraphics();
JButton but = new JButton("Click me");
but.update(gfx);
```

But that's really really really ugly !

Why don't you take a JPanel? Afaik you can overwrite the paint method to just call the update method so the panel doesn't get cleared (but it has been a while that I was playing with Java). Then you can use the Graphics2D you get as argument in the update method to draw stuff and it allows you to even add your own buttons and other stuff to it...

Comment: That's a possible solution however, that would mean using passive rendering through the paint() method which I have chosen not to do since I want to do active rendering.